# is there a way to 'auto-box' elements in a list, in F#?

Tags: f#

Let's say I have a bunch of types that all implement *IMyInterface*

and then I have a lot of this:

```
myTypeInstance1(...) |> registerIt
myTypeInstance2(...) |> registerIt
myTypeInstance3(...) |> registerIt
...
myTypeInstance30(...) |> registerIt
myTypeInstance31(...) |> registerIt
...
```

where *registerIt* is taking a type that implements *IMyInterface*

It would be convenient if I could collect all these instances into a list, but then the syntax becomes awkward:

```
[
    box (myTypeInstance1(...))
    box (myTypeInstance2(...))
    box (myTypeInstance3(...))
    ...
] |> List.iter registerIt
```

or,

```
[
    myTypeInstance1(...) :> IMyInterface
    myTypeInstance2(...) :> IMyInterface
    myTypeInstance3(...) :> IMyInterface
    ...
] |> List.iter registerIt
```

is there a way to build such a list without having to explicitly box / cast every element individually?

Answer (score 4):

Putting a type annotation on the list itself should do the trick:

```
let objs : List<IMyInterface> =
    [
        MyType1()
        MyType2()
        MyType3()
    ]
objs |> List.iter registerIt
```